# How to transform this piece of code using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to transform this piece of code using Java 8.

```
private boolean hasOneFuelType(final List<PoiBE> pois) {
        for(PoiBE poiBE: pois) {
            if(poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, in the code above I want to return false if in the list of pois has at least one poi that has a   list of Types that is bigger then 1, otherwise I want to return true.

I tried this code, but apparently is not correct.

```
pois.stream().anyMatch(poiBE -> {
    if(poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1) {
      return false;
    }
      return true;
});

return true;
```

Comment: Do you always return true after running the stream?

Comment: @daniu yes, because otherwise I am receiving Missing return statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) returns false if any item in the stream matches the given predicate, and true otherwise.

```
return pois.stream()
         .noneMatch(poiBE -> poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close.

The `return` statements inside the `anyMatch` don't return from your method, but from the lambda passed to `anyMatch`:

```
boolean anyHasMoreThanOneFuelType = pois.stream().anyMatch(poiBE -> {
    if(poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
});

return !anyHasMoreThanOneFuelType;
```

This of course can be simplified if you replace `anyMatch` with `noneMatch` and skip the unnecessary `if` by directly returning the boolean result of the comparison:

```
return pois.stream().noneMatch(
    poiBE -> poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
return pois.stream()
       .noneMatch(poiBE -> poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return pois.stream().allMatch(
    poiBE -> poiBE.getDetails().getSimpleRefueling().getTypes().size() <= 1);
```